# What is the state space of fermions in lattice QFT, in position space, in the Schrödinger picture?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, fermions, lattice-model

Let me motivate this question by analogy:

- In classical mechanics with $N$ particles in $d$ dimensions, trajectories are $\mathbf{r}: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^{2d \cdot N}$, and the state at time $t$ is $\mathbf{r}(t)\in \mathbb{R}^{2d\cdot N}$.  Time evolution is $\mathbf{r'}(t)=Ω\,\mathrm{d}\mathcal{H}$.
- In quantum mechanics, in position space, trajectories are $\Psi: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}^{\mathbb{R}^{d\cdot N}}$, and the state is $\Psi(t):\mathbb{R}^{d \cdot N} \to \mathbb{C}$ (properly a [ray](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_Hilbert_space) in $L_2(\mathbb{R}^{d \cdot N},\mathbb{C})$). Time evolution is $\Psi'(t)=\frac{-i}{ℏ}\hat{H}\Psi(t)$.
- In QFT, for a bosonic field $\phi$ with field configuration space  $\Phi:\mathbb{R}^{d}\to V$, trajectories are $\Psi: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}^{\Phi}$, and the state is a wave-functional $\Psi(t): \Phi \to \mathbb{C}$ (properly a ray in $L_2(\Phi,\mathbb{C})$). Time evolution is $\Psi'(t)=\frac{-i}{ℏ}\hat{H}\Psi(t)$. <sup>(Jackiw '87, Hatfield '92, Polonyi '14)</sup>

In practice, uncountably infinite wave-functional components cannot be simulated. But *in principle*, applying time evolution to an element of $P(L_2(\Phi,\mathbb {C}))$ will generate the trajectory & the observed position-space dynamics in terms of field configurations, whence occupied states with bosonic statistics arise.

*In principle*, what is the state space of position-space wave-functionals for a fermionic field?

(Hatfield '92 notes its existence but does not elaborate. Freed '01 & Avramidi '01 discuss classical fermionic fields and field functionals but don't explicitly answer either.)

(Ignore normalization, smoothness, mixed states, gauge invariance, relativity, fermion doubling, all numerical issues, etc.)

Comment: If you like, the Hilbert space of a fermionic field on the lattice could be expressed as $\mathcal{H} = \bigotimes_{\vec{x}} \mathbb{C}^2$, i.e. a qubit at each spatial point $\vec{x}$.  In contrast, for a bosonic field, we would have $\mathcal{H} = \bigotimes_{\vec{x}} L^2(\mathbb{R})$, where the $\mathbb{R}$ in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ corresponds to values of the field $\phi$.

Comment: @EmmyNoether You’re sure the field configurations are just $\mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{C}^2$, no exterior (Grassmann) algebra elements?  And that generates the appropriate dynamics to give rise to occupied states with fermionic statistics?  Authors (e.g. Freed & Avramidi) seem to assert the (super)field is valued in an exterior algebra.